# Search in favorited questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, bookmarks

I wonder if it is possible to search in just my favorited questions?

If not, can it be considered as a feature request?

Comment: Did you favorite every question?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question

Comment: @squillman: now your comment seems too ironic.

Comment: @voy infinite loop for the win!

Comment: I think searching within favs is a good idea. Not because I have every question as my favorite but I do use favorite feature as bookmarking on SO.

Comment: The option `infavorites:1` was implemented in August 2010, but [no longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test) since the new search was introduced early 2011.

Comment: Why is `infavorites` no longer supported? I use that search term a lot, and it's quite handy. (@Arjan's link is broken.)

Comment: See also [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality). (@Pat)

Comment: Could [the search hints page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) be updated?

Comment: @Welbo'clock, favorites are somewhat like browser bookmarks And every decent browser provides a search feature for its bookmarks.

Comment: Personally, I am giving up on favorites and just using bookmarks. I would rather that favoriting were disabled so that I would never have fallen into the trap of favoriting in the first place.

Comment: could we remove the `status-completed` tag? maybe this was removed by accident, in which case it is *again* a `feature-request`. if it was removed by intent (I hope not) then it would be *now* a `status-declined`.

Comment: fyi, it works again.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

<sup>From my original answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43736/add-favourites-tab-after-tag-search/49986#49986):</sup>

I think the most flexible solution would be to add a search parameter `infavorites:x` that would allow searches on people's favourited questions.

The parameter `x` would be one of:

- A numeric user id
- `mine`, a shortcut to search your own favourites
- `all`, to search in all users' favourites

This plays well with all the existing search parameters.

Since everyone's favourites are public anyway (and are included in the data dump), I don't see a problem exposing this type of feature in search.

Comment: Yes please! My favorites have gotten too much! I was actually looking for a way to filter/search all my favorites by tag.

Comment: Not able to use this now, Is it still available? Please let me know any new syntax to search in favorites.

Comment: @mtk: It existed at one time, but was removed when question search was rewritten.

Comment: So, how to search in favorites now ? Have asked same question on meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140540/search-in-favorites), Please reply if you know the answer.

Comment: @mtk: You can't. Look at [Revision 5 of this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3683/revisions) -- it was implemented at one time, but was removed during the rewrite of the search code.

Comment: This is now how it works, with the exception of the `all` option...that one's crazy expensive without an indexing change and can't see a real win by implementing it.  That being said, we *could* do it a different way if it was really helpful.

Comment: does this still work, with the new changes in the search system? it replaces `mine` to my user id, but there is no result. :(

Comment: if this is deprecated, could it be noted in the answer?

Comment: @naxa: This still appears as an option in the Advanced Search Tips. Go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q= and click the Advanced Search Tips link at the top right. The search box recognizes the option, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

Comment: @JonSeigel yes I've tried it, but it didn't work. So do we have `[status-needs-fix]`? I suggested in the A's comment that the `[status-completed]` tag should be removed. Not only would that reflect the reality (in the sense that it's no longer 'complete' due to regression) but may also attract attention.

Comment: @naxa: I would suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: @JonSeigel Wow thanks! That's pretty cool! Now I can search my favorites by tag! `infavorites:mine [tag]` :D

Answer (score 61):

I currently have 1850 questions favorited for various reasons.  Many of them have good answers in them (I can't favorite answers, grrr) or otherwise have information relevant to me.  Some of them I want to track over a period of time.  Some are just amusing or otherwise illustrative of programmer peculiarities.

I would welcome some kind of search facility on my favorites, even if it just found a keyword or two in the text of the questions or answers, or if I have to use a special string in Google to accomplish it.

Actually, filtering the favorites on a specified tag would work too.

Comment: Good point; very reasonable, I would say...  +1

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE:** infavorites:mine has been implemented.

Only American spelling of favorites is supported.

---

I have found [stackoverflow favorites organizer](https://stackapps.com/q/2438) by googling.

It works well in Chrome but I had issues with it in Firefox. Not perfect but I managed to find the question I was looking for reasonably quick.

I hope `infavorites:mine` will be implemented soon.

Comment: `infavorites:mine` automatically got converted to `infavorites:4790871` for me, which appears to implement everything desired. Horray

Comment: Didn't auto-convert to me, but this happily indicated to me how to do it (find my user ID).

Comment: I just wasted a few minutes of my life wondering why this wasn't working. It's because only *American spelling* of *favorites* is supported. That should be highlighted.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Sorry to hear that. :( I added that to the answer for future visitors.

Comment: Ten years pass, but not implemented yet =(

Answer (score 16):

This could be part of an [advanced search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/add-an-advanced-search-page).

Comment: `s/could/should/r`

Comment: @perbert, what is the r modifier for s command? Havent found it anywhere :-)

Comment: @Tomas, `s/r/g/g` :P

Comment: @perbert, uff, I searched all the manpages for that! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This has now been completed with the new elasticsearch engine, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/13295).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done by adding to your search query the following:

***infavorites:mine***

So as an example, to find posts you favorited that have "notification" mentioned in the title you would type this in the search box:

***notification infavorites:mine***

A list of more search operators can be found on the help page here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: I just wasted a few minutes of my life wondering why this wasn't working. It's because only *American spelling* of *favorites* is supported. That should be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JS snippet you can use as a bookmark. Mark the full code and drag it on your bookmark bar or paste it into the url field when editing a bookmark.

```
javascript:(function(){var i=$("input[name=q]").val("infavorites:mine ")[0];i.focus()})()
```

This bookmark can be used on all StackExchange pages to initialise a search in your favourites.

Remembering `infavorites:mine` in my rare cases that I actually need to search through my favourites was too hard for me, so I made this bookmark for me.

I also wanted to be able to use it on all of my StackExchange sites, so that's why the bookmark won't redirect you to any search site. Go to your StackExchange site of your choice and click the bookmark for the favourite search, afterwards.

EDIT: The code I provided above will not work on the main StackExchange site to search through all your favorites from ALL StackExchange sites, though. For a proper solution to this problem, please check [Cross-site inbookmarks:mine search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315037/cross-site-inbookmarksmine-search).

Comment: is there a way to search among the upvoted questions. also, how is the $ working in pure javascript, isn't it a jquery function, and you have not imported jquery?

Comment: @vikrant The `$` is working, because jQuery is available and loaded on all SE sites. Remember that you execute the script in the scope of the website itself, when you click on the bookmark. It means that you can access all JavaScript objects that are available. So I used it, to make my snippet easier to understand.

Comment: @vikrant Regarding searching upvoted questions. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching. As far as I know, you can search for upvoted questions by using `score:50` (filter by 50 or more upvotes), however there is no way to find only your upvoted questions.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me, i never thought about the 'scope' in which it is executing. also, i wanted to search among my upvoted questions, but apparently it doesn't work. from now on i will favourite every question i upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of when (and why) this keyword changed, but the Search Help lists the following:

```
inbookmarks:mine
```