# Search within Favorites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in favorited question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question)

The favorite feature on SO is right now a bit useless, at least to me.

I have 8 Pages of favorites, and sometimes I just remember "Hey, I favorited a question about the problem I'm having!", but I don't know when, so the sorting doesn't help.

I would love to see a new search-keyword "favorite:1" that only searches within my favorites. That way I could use it as my bookmark/personal search scope.

Comment: Does that help? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question

Comment: A bit, but not really. That way, I have titles, but sometimes the desired string is in the questions or one of the answers. I had 2 or 3 times where I only knew "it was something about jQuery in one of my favorites", and that was hard to find :)

Comment: @Michael: The accepted answer or any of the other answers for that matter maybe didn't help, but this *is* the same feature request, no?

Comment: There are some more thing that can be done for favorites. have a look at my post and vote up if you agree: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements

Comment: For those who came here via Google, like me, this does work now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176861/229177

Comment: TLDR: infavorites:mine

Answer (score 35):

A search for all parts of your profile would be good - favourites, comments, answers. Something that becomes available after 100 reputation perhaps.