# Add favourites tab after tag search

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Suppose I search for the tag [Python]. I should be able to have a tab that would display all of my favourites for Python. Don't make me think.

Comment: Go to your favorites page, then hit Ctrl+F (Windows) or Cmd+F (Mac). Type in 'Python' (or whatever tag).

Comment: @waiwai: I have 14 pages

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in list of favorited questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think a more flexible solution would be to add a search parameter `infavorites:x` that would allow searches on people's favourited questions.

The parameter `x` would be one of:

- A numeric user id
- `mine`, a shortcut to search your own favourites
- `all`, to search in all users' favourites

This plays well with all the existing search parameters.

Since everyone's favourites are public anyway (and are included in the data dump), I don't see a problem exposing this type of feature in search.

Comment: Nice. But if time is spent on a new search option, I'd rather be able to search in *all* favorites (sorry, I don't care about favorites of specific users, though I could understand one wants to search ones own favorites). Hence, maybe `xx` could be left out altogether to search within all favorites?

Comment: @Arjan: `infavorites:all`? (Also, thanks for the edit.)

Comment: Yup, sounds good to me. :-) (I doubt I would ever use this search option, but at least it wouldn't be limited to a certain usage.)

Comment: That sounds really, really useful. If you want to find the best questions on a tag, one option is to just look at votes. Another is to find a really active user and look at their tags. Now with the API, we could do even more like subtract those questions you've already favourited or look at the favourites of a few top users