# Improved localised search

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, search

I am suggesting to have **local search** to search only those question related to the user i.e. question asked or answered to. I have been a user for just 2 months and I already have 7 pages to scroll for answers. Now, I want to refer them in future, I have to search between hundreds of questions of same type (mostly duplicates) OR search through my 7 pages of answers list which will continue to grow in future.

I already went through [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49986/221351) from here, which is a Global Level Search, and also went through **Advanced search tips(AST)**. Now, suppose I want to find all the answers I post which contains word *`Eclipse`*, then I must search like this:-

```
user:2345913 is:answer body:"Eclipse"
```

Which is good and I get what I desire, but, its bit complicated. I had to understand these **AST** myself for simple short query. I would want it to be simpler, like this:

> [image: Image here...]

***Pros:-***

- Very simple and can be fast.
- Can be easily understood and **can use by new users**.(who has no
  knowledge of advance serach tips.)
- This will be a local level search i.e. it will search in currently
  logged-in site and not cross site (if you have multiple SE accounts.)
- Can be fast search for (localised) self-answered, (localised) self
  question, (localised) self-favourites, *which is frequent search for all SE sites users* whether new or old, who want to refer what they have already done.
- Well, there is space out there use it.
- And... Well you add more (Open for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion))

***Cons:-***

- Matter of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) - all are welcome. :)

Comment: I would love to have this feature. I often search for stuff in my questions and answers and this would be useful.

Comment: +1, I support this feature.

Comment: +1, one of the few good feature requests by new users `:)`

Comment: Your screendump [is lacking some important current functionality](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNH9U.png). But I see that you want this to be even more local than that. I wouldn't mind, but don't see a lot of added functionality either -- unless it would ADD search for comments.

Comment: @Arjan my concern is having to understand Advance search tips for simple query like searching *Eclipse* keyword in answers/question which **I** answered/asked. This feature will also help those who are ignorant of Advance search tips and this would be fast local search. Searching for comments wont add value..

Comment: But as shown in my screenshot, that advanced search is pre-filled. And that's all you need if you want to search in all your own posts (questions *and* answers, not comments). (To me, searching for *my* comments actually *does* add value; always need to use Google or an RSS archive for that, but that works fine too.)

Comment: @Arjan only accountID is pre-filled... You need to add `is:answer body:"some test"` to search in Answer section... I know and understand Advance search tips **(AST)** and so it looks fine. But, how many of SO users do you think fully knows and understands AST.. What about new user... Lets make it simple, the most frequent local search..

Comment: As an aside: you can skip the `body` part. And like I wrote: I understand you want to limit on only questions *or* answers. For me, that has no added value, but I wouldn't mind (if extra search boxes wouldn't confuse people).

Comment: @Arjan that `body` part was the main reason why this post is there... About the confusion.., I don't think it will add confusion, it can also be included in FAQ if required...

Comment: Would "Add context aware search" be a better title? ("Localised" feels like i18n-related.)

Comment: What's up with all those very minor edits? You do realize you're very close to making this a Wiki post, right?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd want to boost up, Cant find any SE employees participation here,, And I dont really care about rep in META,,.. Thanks, for your concern though.. :)

Comment: Bounty is more than enough, trying to keep a question on top too much usually ends up more annoying than really useful.

Comment: Related: a similar search box for comments in [Ability to search comments would be useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183142/ability-to-search-comments-would-be-useful).

Answer (score 6):

Did you also see `user:me` in the Advanced Search Tips? I use it pretty often, and it works exceptionally well for me.

In short, what you want is a search box which runs the following query for "Eclipse":

```
user:2345913 is:answer body:"Eclipse"
```

I assert that your suggested feature is unnecessary, because it's sufficient to type:

```
user:me Eclipse
```

- `user:me` is easier to remember than "user:2345913", so this choice is obvious.
- **`is:answer` can be left out at the cost of getting *some* extra results.**
- `body:` is removed, because answers cannot have titles, and questions whose title contain "Eclipse" will probably have the word "Eclipse" in the body as well.

The only disadvantage of my method is boldfaced: You *may* get some extra unwanted results. In my opinion, this is a good trade-off, for the following reasons:

- There's no need to add extra clutter to the profile page.
- One does not have to navigate to the profile page in order to search for an answer. In fact, the existing method (using `user:me`) is more powerful than the suggested feature, because it can be used at tag-specific pages. I find it easier to append `user:me` at the [google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) page, than to type `[google-chrome-extension]` in the suggested search box.
- If your question contains all search keywords, it *could actually be relevant*! With the suggested search box, one has to search through their own questions as well to look for the desired post.

(Note: My point of view might be biased, because I've only asked two questions and posted 2.2k answers on Stack Overflow - I seldom see my own questions in the search results).

Comment: Looks good, But again there is need for understanding Advance search tips(AST), I mean, it took me awhile to understand and now I can play with it, but what about new users say 3 months active members. There are a majority % of users who are active on SE sites and are unaware of this **AST** . This is a frequent search, why make it complicated.

Comment: I'd like to add to what @CRUSADER said, I think putting the search button there in addition to where it is would make a nice addition to the UX of the site.

Comment: Even more, this [is already pre-filled on every profile page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNH9U.png), for any user one looks at.