# Searching within the list of favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

I keep a list of favorite questions in SO. The idea is to keep questions that can be useful in the future there, being a kind of reference. When that list grows beyond a certain point, however, it becomes more and more difficult to find the exact question that I was looking for.

Does SO have any mechanism for searching only in my personal list of favorite questions? If not, are there any plans/interest to implement such a feature? I believe it could be very useful for many SO users.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I searched for it before I posted my question, but nothing came up... Anyway thanks for the link. That is exactly what I was looking for. The bad news is that it seems that implementing such a feature is deferred at this moment.