# Limit search in Stack Overflow to my favorites

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

Is there a way in Stack Overflow to limit a search to within my questions only, or to search within my favorite questions only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your asked questions:

Type this in search box. And hit enter.

```
user:me is:question
```

And there is no way to add field for favorite question [in search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) .

Comment: Why the downvote for this answer? That should work just fine?

Comment: @Bart: because this answer was originally very, very poor. Poor enough (in the untracked five-minute edit window) that I couldn't figure out what it was trying to communicate. It's since been improved, and I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @ Michael Petrotta: I have added only last line in my revision. And other answer was also correct. But thanks for changing your mind.

Comment: No, there were other changes, Somnath. Also, as a side note: remove the space between the `@` and my name, if you want me to be notified of your comment.

Comment: I will take care of that from next time.And do you want me to show screenshot of my latest revision in answer?

Comment: Again, Somnath, I'm not notified of your comments unless you [prefix them correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (you'll see this, because I'm responding directly to your answer).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Yes, I understood now.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Ah, fair enough. I thought I saw the first revision of this (and couldn't explain the downvote), but apparently there was something before it.