# How to search for particular words/tags in user's Favorited questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks, favorites-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

I have come across the `infavorite:x` syntax for searching in favorites, but this no more works.

**My Question:** How to search for particular words/tags in user's Favorited questions?

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but the answer to that question no more works. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature turns out to not yet be present.

Via a comment to this (accepted) answer it turned out that a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50368/182516) was asked before.

**Note**: that comment is deleted again.