# Question closed as duplicate but didn't got the exact answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Search in favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140540/search-in-favorites)

I had asked a question [how to search in favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140540/search-in-favorites/) previously on this meta site. It was closed marking it as a duplicate, but still I didn't get any exact answer. The answer to the original question referenced is no more the correct answer and does not work now.

Can anyone let me know, is there any way to search in a users' favorite questions ? I have a long list of favorites which I need to search and the current paging navigation provided in the favorite tab in the profile is not efficient for searching.

#### Note:

Asked a new question for this, as the previous question is closed, I have casted a reopen vote, but it still requires 4 more reopen votes. Also, I can't start a bounty for the same as it is closed. So to address this concern I have asked a new question. Please let me know, if you find this as not a proper question, and I will delete it, instead of this again being marked as a duplicate.

-Thanks

Comment: The duplicate has "status-deferred", the explanation of which reads *"This suggestion has merit, but it isn't the very next thing on our list. We'll try to get to it."*... there's your answer. If you want it to get renewed attention, consider placing a bounty with a clear explanation of what you expect to get out of it.

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know the "status-deferred". So, this tag  was added to the original question on 10 Jul 2011, Is there any way to keep track of such feature-request, to get to know the status of this, please.

Comment: Not really. Some of them might be tagged [Status-Planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) at some point, but that doesn't always happen. And you can always look at the [list of feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) to see if something appears.