# Favorites search or filtering

Tags: support, search, bookmarks, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

Is it possible to search a phrase in my own favorite questions? Is it possible to filter my favorites by tag (e.g. tag `css` and I will see only `css` tags)?

Comment: If you're talking 'favorite tags' then this is the [feature request you want](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags), or are you talking favorite questions?

Comment: No, I am talking about favorites at my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has just been recently implemented with the new elasticsearch engine, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/13295).

So, for your specific search just enter this in the search box:

> [css] infavorites:mine

Comment: Great, thank you. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Do a search, then click the link on the right-hand side "Advanced Search Tips".