# How can I do a cross Stack Exchange search of all my bookmarked questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, stack-exchange, bookmarks, elasticsearch

*Single Stack search:*

We can [already search our bookmarks within a *single Stack Exchange site*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3683/160519) by using `inbookmarks:mine <insert-search-terms-here>`, which uses [elasticsearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/160519) behind the scenes.

[image]

*Feature Request*

The single-site `inbookmarks:mine` search is really useful.  I hope for an enhancement to our current capabilities.  I have bookmarks spread across at least 20 different Stack Exchange sites.  Some of those sites have technology overlaps... as an example, I could find answers to bash shell or TCP questions on at least five different Stack Exchange sites.  Often I know I bookmarked a question somewhere, but I can't remember which site I bookmarked it.

Please enable search across all my Stack Exchange favorites by using `inbookmarks:mine <insert-search-terms-here>` from the [Stack Exchange search box](https://stackexchange.com/search).  In other words, this query should return a search of all my bookmarks across all Stack Exchange sites:

[image]

I realize this may require a change from Google search to [elasticsearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/160519); I hope this request is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less possible with a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query; I've written one [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1435914/search-in-favorite-questions?AccountId=338430&query=this) where it's looking for the word 'this' in your bookmarked questions:

[image]

Please keep in mind SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.